# Why can't simple blood transfusions be used for treatment of COVID-19, instead of plasma transfusions?

Tags: covid-19, blood, treatment, antibodies, plasma

It has been recently been shown that convalescent plasma from previously infected patients can be used to help others gain immunity against the disease. But why do we need to use plasma for this purpose? Wouldn't a simple blood transfusion work too given that it contains plasma and antibodies?

Comment: What are your sources?

Comment: @Thomas is correct. You need to name your source for this claim. Also, what has your research revealed?

Answer (score 2):

The Red Cells can be used for other purposes like blood transfusions.  It's not necessary for whole blood transfusions as far as we know.

Plasma is the part of blood that remains after the red cells, white cells and platelets are removed.  Blood type AB people are considered universal plasma donors because they don't carry Anti-A or Anti-B in their plasma.  Whereas Group O negative people are considered universal red cell donors because their red cells lack the A and B antigens.

However, there is some data to suggest the virus can affect haemoglobin synthesis but whether that is meaningful, no one knows.

https://www.urmc.rochester.edu/encyclopedia/content.aspx?ContentTypeID=160&ContentID=37

https://chemrxiv.org/articles/COVID-19_Disease_ORF8_and_Surface_Glycoprotein_Inhibit_Heme_Metabolism_by_Binding_to_Porphyrin/11938173

Comment: Hm, but isn't it more tricky to get plasma donations as you need specialized machine and a larger quantity of blood?

Comment: We presume that we are in at least 1st world country.  If you're not, then please modify your question.